# Need to add Comparable without modifying the class that is comparing

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

Code:

```
LinkedBinarySearchTree <Pair<String, Integer>> at = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>();
Pair<String, Integer> p = new Pair<>(str, dni);
at.insert(p);
```

Pair is a class that has been given to me, it isn't the java class Pair (idk if java has a default pair class but just in case it has one, this one isn't that).

The class pair doesn't have a `compareTo` defined in it and the method `insert` uses the compareTo at some point and when it does it crashes.

I need to implement the abstract class Comparable and override the method compareTo in the class from the outside, without modifying the code of the class Pair, which means I have to do it from the "outside".

Is there a way to do this?

This is what I did previously:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator <Pair<String, Integer>> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<String, Integer> o1, Pair<String, Integer> o2) {
           final Collator instance = Collator.getInstance();
            instance.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);


        if (!o1.getFirst().equals(o2.getFirst())){
            return o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst());
        } else {
            return o1.getSecond().compareTo(o2.getSecond());
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with Comparator, it has to be Comparable for some reason and I don't know how to do it because I can't refer (this):

```
public class MyComparable implements Comparable <Pair<String, Integer>> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair<String, Integer> o) {
           final Collator instance = Collator.getInstance();
            instance.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);

        //I can't use "this" here because ovbiously I'm not inside the class Pair so I don't know how to do it
        if (!this.getFirst().equals(o.getFirst())){   //I can't use "this"
            return this.getFirst().compareTo(o.getFirst());
        } else {
            return this.getSecond().compareTo(o.getSecond());
        }
    }
}
```

I need help please I've been trying to find an answer by myself and I'm out of ideas... I'm sorry if this question is too easy or unhelpful but I'm kinda struggling here :/.

EDIT:
I debugged the program and this is where it crashes, that's why I
think I need the Comparable:

```
public class DefaultComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> {
    @Override
    public int compare(E a, E b) throws ClassCastException {
        return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b); //here
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be confused. Just because *your* Comparator isn't working doesn't mean that a better Comparator isn't the solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "crashes"? Do you get an exception? If so which one? Is it a `ClassCastException` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you possibly extend `Pair` with you own class that also implements `Comparable` and use that?

```
public class MyPair<T, O> extends Pair<T, O> implements Comparable<MyPair<T, O>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyPair<T, O> other) {
           //logic to compare
    }
}
```

and then use that

```
LinkedBinarySearchTree <MyPair<String, Integer>> at = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>();
```

**Edit based on comments:**
If you know the types of objects used in the `Pair` are themselves `Comparable` then you can use bounded generic parameters. So the example above becomes:

```
public class MyPair<T extends Comparable<T>, O extends Comparable<O>> extends Pair<T, O> implements Comparable<MyPair<T, O>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyPair<T, O> other) {
           //Now the compiler knows that T and O types are Comparable (that 
           //is they implement the Comparable interface) and 
           //this means their compareTo() can be used

           return this.getFirst().compareTo(other.getFirst()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: hey idk if im doing something wrong but I cant use the compareTo String default java method. For example here: `return this.getSecond().compareTo(other.getSecond());`   It's like this.getSecond() returns me an Object and not a String

Comment: You're trying to compare the `getSecond()` from this Pair and `getSecond()` from the other pair by calling .compareTo()... but the getSecond() is of type O which can be any type so the compiler doesn't know that these are Comparable. You'll need to make these bound generic parameters... I'll ammend my original anser...

Comment: @randomstudent2332 I've expanded on my original answer ... does it make sense?

Comment: yes! it works now and doesn't crash and im so thankful to you for that but... yeah sorry for keep bothering you but just one more thing. If I needed my program to return at the end (after doing all the inserts and stuff) Pair<String, Integer> and not MyPair<String, Integer> is there a way to make it return that? Like a way to convert MyPair to Pair.

Comment: That's ok. Using the principals of inheritence if Cat extends Animal then Cat is a Cat and Cat is also an animal... Meaning you can cast Cat into Animal...  so in your case do you mean you want to return LinkedBinarySearchTree <Pair<String, Integer>> rather than LinkedBinarySearchTree <MyPair<String, Integer>>?

Comment: yes! I must return LinkedBinarySearchTree <Pair<>> for the method to past the tests

Comment: So if you were returning just the Pair instance itself this wouldn't be a problem (because MyPair IS A Pair already due to what I explained a minute ago) but because your using MyPair as a type parameter for `LinkedBinarySearchTree` you wouldn't be able to change the type parameter from MyPair to Pair no

Comment: oh bummer, but that's ok I think you pointed me in the right direction and now I understand how all of it works better, I'll ask tomorrow in class for help. Ty!

Comment: The cloest you could do is a wild card in your generic return type... So    `public LinkedBinarySearchTree<? extends Pair> myMethodToCreateATree() {  ... //create the tree as we've discussed and then just return it }`

Comment: So what you're saying is "I'm returning a `LinkedBinarySearchTree` which has, as a type paremeter, `Pair` or any subclass of `Pair`" (that's what the `? extends X` means)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class to pair without changing pair but adding comparable to wrapper and after that you need to change your linkedlist's generic to ComparablePair

```
class ComparablePair implements Comparable < ComparablePair > {
  private Pair < String,Integer > pair;
  @Override
  public int compareTo(ComparablePair o) {
    Pair otherPair = o.pair;
    //compare this.pair and otherpair here.
    return 0;
  }
}


LinkedBinarySearchTree <ComparablePair> at = new LinkedBinarySearchTree<>();
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change anything from any class so I can't change my linkedlist generic to ComparablePair :/.